# Send selected checkbox dropdown values to MySQL table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and Mysql. I am trying to send multiple checkbox dropdown values to mysql table. But only 1 value going to value. It is last value that go to database. I have tried some others method too. But in the end I am here. Thanks in advance.

**Here is the View.**

```js
<div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control"  data-toggle="dropdown"></select>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" name="sub_cat_id" id="sub_cat_id" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1">
                                <input name="sub_cat_id" id="sub_cat_id"  type="checkbox"/ ><?php echo $this->lang->line('select_sub_cat_message')?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                </div>
                
                <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#item-form').validate({
            rules:{
                name:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4,
                    remote: {
                        url: '<?php echo site_url("items/exists");?>',
                        type: "GET",
                        data: {
                            name: function () {
                                return $('#name').val();
                            },
                            sub_cat_id: function() {
                                return $('#sub_cat_id').val();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                unit_price: {
                    number: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                name:{
                    required: "Please fill item Name.",
                    minlength: "The length of item Name must be greater than 4",
                    remote: "Item Name is already existed in the system"
                },
                unit_price: {
                    number: "Only number is allowed."
                }
            }
        });

        $('#cat_id').change(function(){
            var catId = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo site_url('items/get_sub_cats');?>/'+catId,
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(data){
                    $('#sub_cat_id').html("");
                    $.each(data, function(i, obj){
                     //   $('#sub_cat_id').append('<option value="'+ obj.id +'">' + obj.name + '</option>');
                        $('#sub_cat_id').append('<input name="sub_cat_id" type="checkbox" value="'+ obj.id +'"/>&nbsp;' + obj.name + '');
                    });
                    $('#name').val($('#name').val() + " ").blur();
                }
            });
        });

        $('#sub_cat_id').on('change', function(){
            $('#name').val($('#name').val() + " ").blur();
        });

        $(function () { $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is the controller funtion**

```js
function add()
 {
  if(!$this->session->userdata('is_shop_admin')) {
        $this->check_access('add');
  }
  
  $action = "save";
  unset($_POST['save']);
  if (htmlentities($this->input->post('gallery'))) {
   $action = "gallery";
   unset($_POST['gallery']);
  }
  
  if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')=='POST') {

   $item_data = array();
   foreach ( $this->input->post() as $key=>$value) {
    $item_data[$key] = htmlentities($value);
   }

   $item_data['shop_id'] = $this->get_current_shop()->id;
   $item_data['is_published'] = 1;
   
   //unset($item_data['cat_id']);
   
   if ($this->item->save($item_data)) {   
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Item is successfully added.');
   } else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Database error occured.Please contact your system administrator.');
   }
   
   if ($action == "gallery") {
    redirect(site_url('items/gallery/'.$item_data['id']));
   } else {
    redirect(site_url('items'));
   }
  }
  
  $cat_count = $this->category->count_all($this->get_current_shop()->id);
  $sub_cat_count = $this->sub_category->count_all($this->get_current_shop()->id);
  
  if($cat_count <= 0 && $sub_cat_count <= 0) {
   $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Oops! Please create the category and sub category first before you create items.');
   redirect(site_url('items')); 
  } else {
   if($cat_count <= 0) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Oops! Please create the category first before you create items.');
    redirect(site_url('items'));
   } else if ($sub_cat_count <= 0) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Oops! Please create the sub category first before you create items.');
    redirect(site_url('items'));
   }
  }
  
  $content['content'] = $this->load->view('items/add',array(),true);
  $this->load_template($content);
 }
```

**Here is the Model Function**

```js
 function save(&$data, $id = false)
 {
  if (!$id && !$this->exists(array('id' => $id, 'shop_id' => $data['shop_id']))) {
   if ($this->db->insert($this->table_name, $data)) {
    $data['id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
    return true;
   }
  } else {
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   return $this->db->update($this->table_name, $data);
  } 
  return false;
 }
```

Comment: Thats because all of checkboxes are having the same `name`, so only the last one will be sent.

Comment: but the values are different.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make sense of all your code.  However one guess is that you should be using `<input name="sub_cat_id[]" type="checkbox"/ >` in order to pass the checkboxes as an array, rather than a single value

Comment: please don't use code snippets to format your code!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1**
Forgot to check the obvious, check this in the view

```
 <a href="#" name="sub_cat_id" 
  id="sub_cat_id" 
  class="small" data-value="option1" 
  tabIndex="-1">
  <input name="sub_cat_id" id="sub_cat_id"  type="checkbox"/ >
    <?php echo $this->lang->line('select_sub_cat_message')?>
  </a>
```

U have the same name for the `<a>` and `<input>` tags.

**____________________________________________________________________**

You are sending this to the server

`<input name="sub_cat_id" id="sub_cat_id"  type="checkbox"/ >
<?php echo $this->lang->line('select_sub_cat_message')?>
</a>`

The problem here is with `name="sub_cat_id"` it's a string and u need an array, one way to solve this is to **rename the name** to `name="sub_cat_id[]"`, and to retrieve it in your controller function u can use

```
function functionThatProcessesTheForm(){
     $subCatIds = $this->input->post('sub_cat_id');
     /** 
       subCatIds its an array, the value of each element will be
       the "value" the input had, if it wasn't selected, it will not be
       contained in the array 
     **/
}
```

**Important**

Set the value if the input `value ="theidvalue"`, if u don't the id's will not reach the controller and u will find an array like `[1,1,1,1,1,1]` if the values are set, ur array will be `[id1,id2,id3,...,idn]`

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: I have tried sending it as an array but its sending NULL.

Error Number: 1048

Column 'sub_cat_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `mk_items` (`name`, `cat_id`, `sub_cat_id`, `discount_type_id`, `unit_price`, `formulation`, `item_form`, `packing`, `search_tag`, `description`, `shop_id`, `is_published`) VALUES ('Web Developer', '3', NULL, '14', '155', 'das', 'fdsfs', '165', 'das', 'fsdf sf', '1', 1)

Filename: E:\xampp5\htdocs\usamapharmacy\m-admin\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: Did you set the value of the `<input type="checkbox" name="sub_cat_id" />` ?, leavling it something like `<input type="checkbox" value="someCatId" name="sub_catr_id">`

Comment: **Also**, everytime i'm making a function to process a form (big forms) in the controller method i use `echo json_encode($this->input->post());`, that helps me to check if the values are reaching the function, and how, try it, maybe u are missing a name, or have a typo.

Comment: yes, its reaching the function. But same error occur. NULL value